# Get locations using Graph Api of Facebook for Php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get locations nearest to 1000 distance of user using Facebook Graph Api for Php? I am getting this link of graph api https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000 but not understand how to implement.
Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `file_get_contents` fetch the locations from graph api.

```
file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=store&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_result = $facebook->api('/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000');
```

You will get result in `$search_result`.